# Google Analytics API getting data from last 30 days simple short

Tags: php, date, parameters, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The code that I am using:

```
$ga->requestReportData(8digitidwhichIcorrectlyplaced, array('browser',
'browserVersion'), array('Pageviews'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, 
$start_date=null, $end_date=null, $start_index=1, $max_results=30);
```

Is this getting from last 30 days my pageviews in google analytics?

Thank you!!!!!

Documentation in case:
https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/wiki/GAPIDocumentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. According to the Core Reporting API, both `start_date` and `end_date` are required. Try this:

```
$ga->requestReportData(8digitidwhichIcorrectlyplaced, array('browser',
'browserVersion'), array('pageviews'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, 
$start_date='30daysAgo', $end_date='today', $start_index=1, $max_results=30);
```

The code above is untested, but according to the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate), you should be to do something like I outlined above.

Also, take a look at the [Google Analytics Query Explorer 2](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) for testing out your queries.

Comment: Thanks. But it's the default actually. start date null. end date null.I need to confirm that's true however....... I appreciate a response however.